# exceeding url limit with geojson

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, mapbox, geojson

I want to change geojson for styling my static image but when I change the properties and send a request to mapbox API it gives an error like "Max retries exceeded with url". How can I simplfy my geojson in python?

```
bend = {
      "type": "FeatureCollection",
      "features": [
        {
          "type": "Feature",
          "properties": {every parameter gives error if i fill here.},
          "geometry": {
            "type": "LineString",
            "coordinates": [
              [
                33.299560546875,
                38.79851374178721
              ],
              [
                33.36822509765625,
                38.720876195817276
              ]
            ]
          }
        }
      ]
    }
```

Here is the warning from mapbox API:

Using a large GeoJSON object as an argument to the overlay parameter may result in hitting the 8,192 byte URL length limit. [see More](https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#overlay-options)

Answer (score 0):

You are likely calling the API passing the parameters as part of the URL (the default way).  There's a URL character limit, unrelated to Mapbox.  To get around this, you'll need to use their Tileset approach: https://docs.mapbox.com/api/maps/#geojson